# AML-S905X-CC (Le Potato). How to enable and use UART on 40 pin header as TTY

Tags: overlay, uart

I want to use the UART on the 40 pin header (pins 8 and 10) of the AML-S905X-CC (Le Potato).

I have tried a couple of O/S like Raspbian Stretch Headless and Armbian, and while the boot and work fine, there seems to be no support for the on board UART on the 40 pin header.

I am happy to use any O/S which can provide this.

Do I need to use Device Tree Overlays to enable this?
If so, where can I download the devicetree overlay package and is there a tutorial or some documentation on the process.

If not, how can I use this onboard UART?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do

ROOT###### ARNBIAN ONLY

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libre-computer-project/libretech-overlays/for-4.13.y/overlays/meson-gxl-s905x-libretech-cc-i2c-ao.dts

sudo armbian-add-overlay meson-gxl-s905x-libretech-cc-i2c-ao.dts
```

end ROOT #####

If Ubuntu

```
git clone https://github.com/libre-computer-project/libretech-wiring-tool.git


cd libretech-wiring-tool
 

sudo make
```

Comment: Hi I'm guessing two different code block in base of system, if not check the edit (you can see there how you can format code)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libre-computer-project/libretech-overlays/for-4.13.y/overlays/meson-gxl-s905x-libretech-cc-uarta.dts

sudo armbian-add-overlay meson-gxl-s905x-libretech-cc-uarta.dts

python3 -m serial.tools.miniterm

--- Available ports:
--- Enter port index or full name:
```

Never port appears, but the uarta is working in `/dev/ttyAML6`.

```py
python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    >>> import serial
    >>> ser = serial.Serial()
    >>> ser.baud = 9600
    >>> ser.port = '/dev/ttyAML6'
    >>> ser.open()
    >>> ser.write(str.encode('test'))
    4
    >>>
```

Serial comm over the port `/dev/ttyAML6` works!

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for an answer to this and led me here.  I know this is older, but I wanted to share what I found to maybe help someone else out.  While using the Raspbian port from libretech, you can use the ldto overlay to enable the uart.

```
sudo ldto enable uart-a
```

It's part of the wiring tool referenced in the first reply and it appears to be the same .dts file that the other reply mentions. It maps to the referenced /dev/ttyAML6.

Using `ldto list` listed the overlays available.

listed here:

https://github.com/libre-computer-project/libretech-wiring-tool/tree/master/libre-computer/aml-s905x-cc/dt